# Disable Ripple on ListView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, rippledrawable

In Android 5.0, my ListView produces a ripple effect when clicking a list item. Is there a way to disable this effect? Looking at the docs, I don't see any way (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can remove or replace the list selector using the `android:listSelector` property. The default list selector under Material is `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` which is a bounded ripple.

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:listSelector="@drawable/my_list_selector" />
```

To completely disable selector, you can use a `@null` or `@android:color/transparent` (works better for some Android versions) value as following:

```
<ListView
    ...
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: this removed the ripple but instead gave me a yellow background instead. I used this instead: `android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
<ListView
...
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />
```

This will disable any visual effect of touching. Not very good for the user, but might be useful in special circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create custom list items with their layout, in which you have to change the `android:background` with a drawable without ripple.

Comment: That only covers the ripple... which works most of the time, unless you need a semi-transparent background for your list items