# Xamarin ListView item click animation

Tags: xamarin

For some reason, i have this animation/effect by default when I press any items of my ListView (chat). I dont have any codes for that, it is just present/default.
[image: item press effect]

Why is that? How can I turn it off or on?

Answer (score 1):

It called "Ripple effect".

there are many related question in SO, see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27237195/3814729 .